# Alternatives for sending a parameter

Tags: php, html

I know two ways for sending an ID to another page:

- as URI segment. exemple: http://mypage.com/index.php/ID
- as an input field in a form using POST or GET methods.

Is there another way than these tow?

The purpose is to have a list of records. When the user clicks on one of them, s/he gets the full details of the selected record in a different page.

Comment: `as URI segment. exemple: http://mypage.com/index.php/ID` not working for you? This one is best method suits your situation

Comment: It does, but I would prefer not to display the id in the URI.

Comment: Why don't you try `base64_encode()` to encode id in URL.

Comment: yes, this can be n good way too indeed.
So the third alternative is to store it the session.

Comment: "It does, but I would prefer not to display the id in the URI" — Why? There shouldn't be anything secret about the IDs you use.

Comment: You can't use a session, the value being sent is coming from the user's choice on the page, so you can't have it already stored on the server.

Comment: Why do you not want the ID to show in the URL? That prevents the user from being able to bookmark the page or share the URL...or is that what you want?

Comment: Also, since your real goal was to hide the ID from the URL, you should have stated that in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Is there another way than these two?"
You can store it in `$_SESSION` too. If that what you are curious about.

But it's not the best way with your current problem. 
Simply use GET (www.yourpage.com/records/THEID)

Comment: "When the user clicks on one of them, s/he gets the full details of the selected record in a different page." — You can't use session because the value has to be one that the user picks from the page they are currently viewing.

Comment: Yes session is useless for this.

Comment: Yes, `$_SESSION` is not a way of "sending an ID to another page"...it already has to have been sent sometime previously for it to be possible that it would be in `$_SESSION`  (because you stored it there).

Comment: He asked "Is there another way than these two?"
I answered to it that yes, there is $_SESSION too.
It was not the answer for his problem, but one of his questions.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you might consider this to fall under your first option of a URL segment, but "URL segment" usually means some part of the URL *before* any GET parameters...just to make sure you're aware of this, you can also put in GET parameters in a URL yourself without creating a form.

These days, URI segments like index.php/123 are popular, but traditionally the way to link to a detail page like that was index.php?id=123; then you can access the ID using `$_GET['id']`.